# Как отправить @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Id) в контроллер?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
  @if (item.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId().AsInt())
                {
                using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Id)
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                    }
                }
```

Вот сам вид в html view

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Delete(int Id)
    {
        var session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();
        try
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {

                DBNewsItem newItem = new DBNewsItem();
                newItem.Id = Id;
                session.Delete(newItem);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            NHibernateHelper.CloseSession();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

А вот контроллер, который должен принимать id. Почему ему ничего не приходит?

Comment: "Почему ему ничего не приходит?" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: В контроллер передается модель представления, а не идентификатор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переделал вьюшку под

```
 @Html.Hidden("Id", item.Id)
```

Потом передал через пост в контроллер

```
 public ActionResult Delete(int id){...}
```

На прямую, через имя, обращаюсь Item.Id

Answer (score 3):

В случаях, если

- вы вызываете `XXXFor` не для свойства модели, а для какого-то стороннего объекта
- вы рендерите View через `PartialFor` или какой-то еще способ рендеринга сложного темплйта для поля.

... MVC выставляет `ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix` - в зависимости от имени переменной или от имени свойства в родительской модели.

Делается это для того, чтобы поля для разных Partial Views получили гарантированно разные имена в HTML.

Поэтому в HTML вы получаете не `"id"`, а какой-нибудь `"item_id"`.

Для того, чтобы сбайндить на сервере этот `"item_id"` в параметр `id` нужно посмотреть, какой префикс используется, и вписать его на сервере в виде атрибута параметра контроллера:

Для сложных типов достаточно вписать сам префикс (имя свойства байндер вытянет сам). Для простых - придется вписать полное имя параметра:

```
public ActionResult Delete([Bind(Prefix = "item.id")] int Id)
{
    ...
}
```

Или принимать "модель целиком" (достаточно бессмысленно в вашем слуае) - тогда байндер вытянет данные по имени параметра + имени свойства:

```
public ActionResult Delete(SomeItem item) // забайндит item.Id
{
    ...
}
```

Это же применимо и к случаю, когда "приходит вся модель", но с общим префиксом - `Bind(Prefix = "item")` точно так же срабатывает в случае, если в partial была, например, отрендерена форма редактирования для нескольких полей.

---

Но именно в вашем случае - решение с `@Html.Hidden("Id", item.Id)` надежнее и проще.

Comment: Да, вытаскивать модель не особо идея. В контроллер передается item.Id и почему-то ваш способ не работает. Я с самого начала  просто через метод get вытаскивал переменную ["item.id"] а потом уже подсказали что можно и через Html.Hidden.

Comment: @AshenOne забыл про особенность работы с простыми типами. Там надо полностью имя параметра вписывать. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Наверное в метод приходит вся модель, попробуйте принимать её в метод.

Т.е. ваше определение метода, будет выглядеть следующим образом (если тип модели DBNewsItem)

```
public ActionResult Delete(DBNewsItem model)
```

Comment: Как это, интересно, она "приходит"?